# Problem with rendering nested object in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render a response from REST API. I can fetch the data and and having no issues when render the flat attributes  in the render section. But when i am trying to render the nested objects, I am getting an error.
The error says: ( Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {amount, currency}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)

Postman and console.log response is like this.

```
{
    "totalCost": {
        "amount": 36500,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "title": "Example Services",
    "Date": 1602810449329
}
```

I am not having issue with the `title` and `Date`. but when I am trying to render the `totalCost`, I am getting the error listed above. I have also tried its nested attributes seprately like this But still not working.

```
 <li> Total Cost : {items.totalCost.amount}</li> 
   <li> Total Cost : {items.totalCost.currency}</li>
```

Thanks All.

Comment: What's the result of `{items.totalCost.amount}`?

Comment: You initialize `this.state.items` with `[]`. That's why `[].totalCost.amount` crashes.

Comment: Hi @xehpuk Thanks for your reply. Could you please paste a sample of the code.

Comment: The error is what it says it is. `items.totalCost` is an object, you can't render a JavaScript object in React. Either stringify it with JSON (if you just want to see the values) or render its parts separately `items.totalCost.amount` and `items.totalCost.currency`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you initialize your `items`:

```
this.state = {
  items: [],
  errorMessage: ""
};
```

Your API call is asynchronous. That's why the component will render before you assign the result to `items`.

Initialize it with `null`. Then don't try render it if it's still null:

```
render() {
  const { items, errorMessage } = this.state;
  
  if (!items && !errorMessage) {
    return null; // or a loading indicator
  }

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

By the way: You're setting `errorMessage2` instead of `errorMessage` in your `axios.catch`.

Comment: Hi @xehpuk. Thanks alot dude. its works for me now. The issue was with null array.